# Typescript import .ts files runtime error when trying to run the application using `ts-node-esm`

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, module, ts-node

I use Node.JS workspace with the following structure:

```
root/
    |- build/
    |- ModuleA/
         |- build/
    |- ModuleB/
         |- build/
    |- WebAPI/
         |- build/
         |- server.ts
```

Running the app with `ts-node-esm src/webapi/server.ts` bumps into the following error:

```
CustomError: Cannot find module '/root/webapi/Presenters/RegisterUserPresenter'
```

on the line of `import`:

```
import { RegisterUserPresenter } from "../Presenters/RegisterUserPresenter"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node build/src/webapi/server.js` does the job!